# Is thre any solution to extract borderless table from PDF to CSV?

Tags: python, tabula, pymupdf

[image: Sample table]

This is my example image from pdf file with 75 pages.

Comment: Please read the Code of Conduct: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct on how to ask a question. 
What have you tried so far? What did you do that went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Python and the tabula module. Since it is borderless, you can first find the area dynamically with my get_area function (modify pages number etc.):

```
from tabula import convert_into, convert_into_by_batch, read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate

def get_area(file):
    """Set and return the area from which to extract data from within a PDF page
    by reading the file as JSON, extracting the locations
    and expanding these.
    """
    tables = read_pdf(file, output_format="json", pages=2, silent=True)
    top = tables[0]["top"]
    left = tables[0]["left"]
    bottom = tables[0]["height"] + top
    right = tables[0]["width"] + left
    # print(f"{top=}\n{left=}\n{bottom=}\n{right=}")
    return [top - 20, left - 20, bottom + 10, right + 10]
```

Before conversion, check that the format of your first table looks correct:

```
def inspect_1st_table(file: str):

    df = read_pdf(
        file,
        # output_format="dataframe",
        multiple_tables=True,
        pages="all",
        area=get_area(file),
        silent=True,  # Suppress all stderr output
    )[0]
    print(tabulate(df.head()))
```

Then, use the area to do your table extraction, from pdf to csv:

```
def convert_pdf_to_csv(file: str):
    """Output all the tables in the PDF to a CSV"""
    convert_into(
        file,
        file[:-3] + "csv",
        output_format="csv",
        pages="all",
        area=get_area(file),
        silent=True,
    )
```

In case you need to extract more than 1 table, again start by inspecting them:

```
def show_tables(file: str):
    """Read pdf into list of DataFrames"""
    tables = read_pdf(
        file, pages="all", multiple_tables=True, area=get_area(file), silent=True
    )
    for df in tables:
        print(tabulate(df))
```

And to a batch conversion of all pdf tables to csv format:

```
def convert_batch(directory: str):
    """convert all PDFs in a directory"""
    convert_into_by_batch(directory, output_format="csv", pages="all", silent=True)
```

Comment: Things to play around with are the options: guess=False, stream=True, and the pages argument.

Answer (score 0):

Camelot is a great option for extracting borderless tables. You can use the flavour = stream option for extraction.

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf('sample.pdf', flavor='stream', edge_tol=500, pages='1-end')

#tables from all your pages will be stored in the tables object
tables[0].df

df.to_csv()
```

Comment: could you please be more elaborate how can I achieve this goal.because it fetches other text data as as well.Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: If it fetches extra data, you can do some data cleaning steps on the data frame that is returned. None of the text extractors are 100% accurate.